# Split on pattern in zsh

Tags: linux, shell, parameters, zsh

I want to do something like `${(@s/<->/)param}` where `<->` is a pattern for numbers. If `param=a567b38c898d` then I'd get `(a b c d)`.

*Note: This is not the only case I'd like to solve, so a general solution would be preferred.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can split on patterns, only on literal text. (Although this being `zsh`, I may be wrong and just need to do a little more research.) However, I have found how to use the substitution modifier to replace strings of characters with a specific string which you can subsequently split on. (You'll need to set the `hist_substpattern` option to allow a pattern as the left-hand side of the substitution operator. Still looking if there is a way to enable that just for a single modifier.)

```
$ param=a567b38c898d
$ setopt hist_substpattern
$ print -l ${(s/1/)param:gs/<->/1}
a
b
c
d
```

First, the modifier `:gs/<->/1` replaces each string that matches the pattern `<->` (i.e., the numbers) with a single `1`. Then, the expansion flag `(s/1/)` splits the string on the `.`

Comment: Unfortunately, `$param` is an arbitrary string. I _could_ write a program to generate a string not in `$param`, (or use, say, the SHA512 of a random integer) but that just doesn't sit well with my conscience. :)

Comment: Like I said: more research. I *think* `${(~s/<->/)param}` should word, based on my reading of `man zshexpn`, but it's not working for me at the moment. (Neither is what I posted above, so I think I've got a different problem on my end at the moment.)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work on a (practically) stock Fedora with `zsh 5.02`. Would this qualify as a bug?

Comment: I [posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25592847/1126841) and got an answer which I wasn't entirely satisfied with. I also posted to the zsh-workers mailing list, and it appears that my understanding of `(~)` is flawed (due to inaccurate documentation by the developers' admission). I haven't had a chance to respond to the answer on my question in light of the developers' comment yet. I will say that they suggested something very similar, if not identical, to my initial suggestion (replace arbitrary strings of digits with a fixed string, then split on that).

Comment: Thanks, what would be the way forward, then? My strings are completely arbitrary... and I really don't want to hang on hashes not colliding (however unlikely that may be). Any code that can be run in the config can be run interactively too, so if I hash the PID, someone else could very well hash the PID for their own purpose... It just feels "incorrect" you know what I mean?

Comment: One thought I had is that since the original string is to be split on a string of digits, you can safely replace each such string with a single digit (say, 1), then split on 1.

Comment: You know, I think that would work! (Substitute in a member of the pattern you just removed--guaranteed to be correct!) If you can make another answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I modified this answer to do just that ;)