# Correct usage of ~ parameter expansion flag?

Tags: zsh

According to `man zshexpn` (5.0.2):

> ~      Force  string  arguments  to  any of the flags below that follow within the parentheses to be treated as
>                 patterns.

For example, using the `s` flag to perform field splitting requires a string argument:

```
% print -l ${(s:9:):-"foo893bar923baz"}
foo8
3bar
23baz
```

My reading of the `~` flag suggests that I should be able to specify a pattern in place of a literal string to split on, so that the following

```
% print -l ${(~s:<->:):-"foo893bar923baz"}
```

should produce

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Instead, it behaves the same as if I omit the `~`, performing no splitting at all.

```
% print -l ${(s:<->:):-"foo893bar923baz"}
foo893bar923baz
% print -l ${(~s:<->:):-"foo893bar923baz"}
foo893bar923baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, rereading the question, it's the difference between this:

```
$ val="foo???bar???baz" 
$ print -l ${(s.?.)val}
foo
bar
baz
```

And this:

```
$ val="foo???bar???baz" 
$ print -l ${(~s.?.)val}
foo???bar???baz
```

It operates on the variable, i.e. the "argument" to the split (from your documentation quote). In the first example, we substitute literal `?`, and in the second, we treat the variable as a glob, and there are no literal `?`, so nothing gets substituted.

Still, though, split works on characters and not globs in the substution itself, from the [documentation](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/linux/zsh-doc/zsh_15.html):

```
s:string:
    Force field splitting (see the option SH_WORD_SPLIT) at the separator string.
```

So, it doesn't look like you can split on a pattern. The `~` character modifies the interpretation of the string to be split.

Also, from the same pattern expansion documentation you reference, it continutes:

> Compare with a ~ outside parentheses, which forces the entire
>   substituted string to be treated as a pattern. `[[ "?" = ${(~j.|.)array} ]]`
>   with the EXTENDED_GLOB option set succeeds if and
>   only if $array contains the string ‘?’ as an element. The argument may
>   be repeated to toggle the behaviour; its effect only lasts to the end
>   of the parenthesised group.

The difference between `${(~j.|.)array}` and `${(j.|.)~array}` is that the former treats the values in`array` as global, and the latter treats *the result* as a glob.

See also:

> `${~spec}` Turn on the GLOB_SUBST option for the evaluation of spec; if
>   the ‘~’ is doubled, turn it off. When this option is set, the string
>   resulting from the expansion will be interpreted as a pattern anywhere
>   that is possible, such as in filename expansion and filename
>   generation and pattern-matching contexts like the right hand side of
>   the ‘=’ and ‘!=’ operators in conditions.

Here is a demo that shows the differences:

```
$ array=("foo???bar???baz" "foo???bar???buz")
$ [[ "foo___bar___baz" = ${(~j.|.)array} ]] && echo true || echo false
false
$ [[ "foo___bar___baz" = ${(j.|.)~array} ]] && echo true || echo false
true
```

And for completeness:

```
$ [[ "foo___bar___baz" = ${(~j.|.)~array} ]] && echo true || echo false
true
```

Comment: I understand what the `s` flag does; I'm asking about the `~` flag, which this answer does not address. Please re-read the question. The `~` appears *inside* the parentheses along with the `s` flag; it is not the `~` operator that appears immediately preceding the parameter name (after any flags).

Comment: Updated answer to include example of what the `~` flag does.

Comment: It could be bad wording in the documentation, but I'm pretty sure the argument in `${(s.foo.)bar}` is `foo`, not `bar`.

Comment: The problem I have with the last quote from the docs you show is that there doesn't seem to be any difference between `${~(j.|.)array}` and `${(~j.|.)array}`.

Comment: `bar` is the argument, as I've demonstrated in my examples, per the `${(s.foo.)bar}` comment. It could very well be bad wording in the documentation -- I'm taking an empirical approach here. I've updated the answer to explain and demonstrate the differences of the other comment.

Comment: The fact that the last two produce the same result makes me think that the flag `~` is just irrelevant for the `j` flag. (Which makes sense: what does it mean to join the words with a pattern, rather than a string?) The first example is a syntax error because the flags come before the operator; fixing to `${(j.|.)~array}` outputs true as well.

Comment: I agree, in the context of joining, I can't think of an example where it would have an effect, but that's the difference between inside and outside the parentheses, and it applies to other parameter expansion flags.

Comment: Quick note on some things I learned from the developers. The difference between `${(~j.|.)array}` and `${(j.|.)~array}` is that in the first one, only `|` added by the join are part of the pattern; `|` in the existing array elements are still literal characters. (Imagine an array of file names, one of which is the unfortunately named `a|b`.) In the second one, *all* `|`, whether part of an array element or added by the join, are considered part of the pattern.